# Регулярное выражение для чисел с двумя знаками после запятой

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть валидация `/^\d+$/` она не пропускает сумму в виде `1000.00` (с точкой не пропускает). Как сделать, чтобы пропускало в виде `1.00`, `1000.00` и так далее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java или JavaScript?
По синтаксису - jQuery.

Не путайте Java и JavaScript

```
/^[\d]+(\.[\d]+)?$/.test('#price'); // попробуй
```

Answer (score 6):

Если строго 2 знака после запятой:

```
/^\d+(\.\d\d)?$/
```

Если произвольное количество:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/^(?=.*\d)\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

```js
(/^(?=.*\d)\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/g).test('1'); //true
(/^(?=.*\d)\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/g).test('1.002'); //false
(/^(?=.*\d)\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/g).test('1.2'); //true
(/^(?=.*\d)\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/g).test('1.22'); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

огромное всем Вам спасибо за помощь, решился благодаря вот такому решению

```
/^-?(?:\\d+|\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})+)(?:\\.\\d+)?$/
```